# "have got " along with "no" usage

Tags: grammaticality

I am not a native English speaker. I want to know whether the following sentence is grammatically correct or not.

> There is no way you have got to escape

Comment: It's a little unclear.  Can you tell us what you are trying to say with the sentence?

Comment: have got to escape = have to escape: same thing.

Comment: This sentence is certainly unidiomatic, and could mean (among others) "you don't have to escape" or "you have no way to escape" which are entirely different things.

Comment: Grammatically, this is OK.  It sounds weird because *have got to X* is typically used to emphasize X, and it's weird to express that you really, really don't have to escape.  You may want to use *leave* or *go* or *find a way out* instead of *escape* unless the context is specifically about avoiding something life-threatening or dangerous.

Comment: The context here is  X threatens Y that X will not permit any way for Y to escape. Still does it sound unidiomatic?

Comment: @Geethanjali Kotaru: In that case it doesn't mean what you want it to mean. There are many ways to say it. **You can't escape. There's no way out. I'm not going to let you escape /...let you out /...let you get away. You'll never escape** etc.

Comment: @Old Brixtonian thank you